# Featherlight on ajax loaded content

Tags: featherlight.js

I have an issue with Featherlight lightbox on ajax loaded content.

On an upload page, i display a gallery with images opened with the lightbox. It works well on first load. But as soon as i upload a new image, the gallery is refreshed by ajax and the lightbox doesn't work anymore.

I load Featherlight via Jquery that way :

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    var lightbox_url = 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js';
    jQuery.getScript( lightbox_url, function() {
        $('.lightbox-img').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
    });
});
```

I don't see any option on the documentation for this (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/).
Thanks for any help !

Comment: I think it should work (assuming you're using `autoBind`). As usual, without a working example, it's hard to say... Try binding it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you  invoke an ajax call changing the images you have to re-call the featherlight initiation function.

```
$.ajax({url: "xx", success: function(result){
       //your code here 

        $('.lightbox-img').magnificPopup({type:'image'});

}});
```